# change font size of default option of dropdown box

Tags: html, css

**I am working on a mobile website ( 360x640) .**

If you see the defalult option of drop down box in the image (**pink color background**  ) with ask a question button and option as **Select a category ....** ,its font size is very small and I am trying to change its font size using CSS but it is not changing and stays as it is and looks very small .Please help in the CSS !!!!

My frontend Mobile View.

[image]

```css
 body{
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}


     .footer {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:rgb(241, 241, 241);
        color: orangered;
        text-align: center;
      
      }

      .experience
      {
        display: block;
        float: right;
       

      }
      
      
      .see-all{
        float: right; 
        color: orangered;
      }


.choose-form
{
   
    background-color:rgb(246, 229, 246);
    padding: 10px;

}
.orange
{
    background-color:#f78336;
    font-size:30px;
    color:white;

}
 button
{
   
    background-color:#f78336;
    font-size:30px;
    color:white;


}



option{
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<form class="choose-form">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <select class="form-select" id="question">
      <option> <span style="font-size:100px;">Select a category : Love,carrer,more ...</span></option>
      <option> <span style="font-size:100px;">Love</span></option>
      <option> <span style="font-size:100px;">Carrer</span></option>
      <option> <span style="font-size:100px;">Marriage</span></option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <!-- edited line -->
    <span class="priceShow"> ₹99(including GST)</span>
    <span>Ideas what to ask</span>
    <div class="profile-icon" style="justify-content-end;">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning orange">Ask a Question </button>
    </div>
  </nav>
</form>
```

Comment: Try applying the style to the `select` element rather than the `options`.

Comment: Apply the font-size style on the select box as @JohnP said. Moreover, I would like to suggest you try using a more responsive design or using SCSS functions, it would make your life easier when you will work on mobile websites in all widths & heights.

Comment: **Your HTML is invalid.** You cannot have HTML elements like `span` or others inside `option` elements, only text and HTML entities are allowed. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many browsers will apply default styles to `select` dropdowns so for your styling to apply you will need to undo this default styling with the following. The variants are for different browsers.

```css
select {
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```css
body {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:rgb(241, 241, 241);
    color: orangered;
    text-align: center;
}
.experience {
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
.see-all {
    float: right; 
    color: orangered;
}
.choose-form {
    background-color:rgb(246, 229, 246);
    padding: 10px;

}
.orange {
    background-color:#f78336;
    font-size:30px;
    color:white;
}
button {
    background-color:#f78336;
    font-size:30px;
    color:white;
}
option {
    font-size: 50px;
}
select {
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form class="choose-form">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <select class="form-select" id="question">
      <option> <span style="font-size:100px;">Select a category : Love,carrer,more ...</span></option>
      <option> <span style="font-size:100px;">Love</span></option>
      <option> <span style="font-size:100px;">Carrer</span></option>
      <option> <span style="font-size:100px;">Marriage</span></option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <!-- edited line -->
    <span class="priceShow"> ₹99(including GST)</span>
    <span>Ideas what to ask</span>
    <div class="profile-icon" style="justify-content-end;">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning orange">Ask a Question </button>
    </div>
  </nav>
</form>
```